# Javascript asset not enqueuing with the rest

Tags: javascript, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I am working on a project that uses the child-theme's functions file to enqueue a stylesheet and a single javascript file. These two resources are enqueued well. However, when I add a new compiled javascript file, it doesn't seem to enqueue past the original two scripts at all, as if it is completely ignoring my addition to the functions.php file. Any idea why this is?

```
    <?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles_and_scripts' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles_and_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/fonts/icons/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js');
       wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/compiled.js');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) contains the same handle (the same ID) as the first `wp_enqueue_script()`.

The handle is the ID by which a registered script is known to WordPress internally. If you use this ID a second time, the second script won't be registered.

A working example could be this one:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles_and_scripts' );
function theme_enqueue_styles_and_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/fonts/icons/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'compiled-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/compiled.js');
}
```